# C++ inheritance constructor problems

Tags: c++, class, object, inheritance

I have created 2 classes (**`Entity`** and **`Player`**).

So basically the `Player` class inherits from the `Entity` class, so a `Player` instance is in itself an `Entity` object.

Here is the first class:

```
#include <iostream>

#define print(obj) std::cout << obj << std::endl

class Entity {
    public:
        int xPos, yPos;

    Entity(int xInitPos, int yInitPos) {
        xPos = xInitPos;
        yPos = yInitPos;
    }

    void move(int _x, int _y) {
        xPos += _x;
        yPos += _y;
    }
};
```

The second class **`Player`** needs to have some additional data:

```
int healt;
int level;
```

Here is the part where I got confused, I dont know if I should specify a new constructor for this class because it needs to get 2 additional parameters.

Here is what I did so far:

```
class Player : public Entity {
    public:
        int healt;
        int level;
// I know that this piece of code is wrong
    Player(int _level, int _healt) {
        level = _level;
        healt = _healt;
    }
};
```

I'm new to C++ programming and I don't know how inheritance works, I also don't know how to create entities of the **`Player`** class and what are the params that it needs.

Here is the main function:

```
int main() {  
    
    Entity ent1 = Entity(0, 0);
    ent1.move(4, 8);

    Player player = Player(what attributes);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can call the base constructor in the child constructor e.g. `Player(int _level, int _health) : Entity(0, 0), level(_level), health(_health) {}` And as you see I use 0, 0 for the `Entity` constructor. So if I wanted to specify the position I would have to adjust my `Player` constructor to also accept `x` and `y` positions: `Player(int _level, int _health, int x, int y) : Entity(x, y), level(_level), health(_health) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't have a default constructor for `Entity` that takes no arguments, you have to initialize it too:

```
Player(int _level, int _healt) : Entity(0 , 0) {
    level = _level;
    healt = _healt;
}
```

Or more idiomatically:

```
Player(int _level, int _healt) : Entity(0 , 0), healt(_healt), level(_level) {}
```

In the above example I initialize by default both positions with 0, if you want to provide the position values yourself, you'll have to have a constructor that takes these values too:

```
Player(int _level, int _healt, int posX, int posY) 
       : Entity(posX , posY), healt(_healt), level(_level) {}
```

And call it like:

```
Player player = Player(1, 100, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what it could look like:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Entity {
    public:
        int xPos, yPos;

    Entity(int xInitPos, int yInitPos) {
        xPos = xInitPos;
        yPos = yInitPos;
    }

    void move(int _x, int _y) {
        xPos += _x;
        yPos += _y;
    }
};

class Player : public Entity {
    public:
        int health;
        int level;
// Constructor that also accepts x and y which are passed on to the base constructor
// The syntax with the : and , separated values is a initializer list.
    Player(int x, int y, int _level, int _health)
    : Entity(x, y)
    , level(_level)
    , health(_health) {}

// Constructor without x and y, passing 0 for x and y to the base constructor
    Player(int _level, int _health)
    : Entity(0,0)
    , level(_level)
    , health(_health) {}
};

int main() {
    Player p(2, 3, 1, 100); // Creates a player at position (2,3) with level 1 and 100 health
    Player p2(2, 110); // Creates a player at position (0,0) and level 2 and 110 health
    std::cout << p.xPos << '\n';
}
```